# set div height by font size and numbers of lines

Tags: javascript, html, height

i want o make a function to set div height automaticly by counting lines. I tried to make it seccessfully but it stops. Please help mi with that.

```
function set_height() {
    var div_obj=document.getElementById('dogodkiinhalt'); //get object by id -> <div>
    var number_of_lines=div_obj.style.offsetHeight; //get number of lines in this obj.
    var font_size=??; //get font size and i don't know how
    var div_Height=number_of_lines*font_size; //calculating new height
    document.getElementById('dogodkiinhalt').style.height = div_Height; //setting new height to div
    }
```

i was looking up how to get text size, but i found nothing. 
wolud be that kind of tkinking ok?

Comment: What's your goal for this?   A div will automatically increase its height to accommodate its content as long as its height isn't explicitly set.  Perhaps you are attempting to fix the wrong problem?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? `div` not wrapping text?

Comment: I think he wants to make DIV scrollable, but sometimes only half of line is visible....

Comment: yap sorry i forgot, i have scrollable div.

Answer (score 0):

just leave the height of the div as auto.

Comment: i can't i have scrollable box. that's whay i need this. 
I declareted height in ccs (like 200px) and if i get more text that shows scrollar. when is less text scrollbar hide and set div height to min posible.